# Переход на активность при нажатии на пункт RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

Есть RecyclerView который выводит несколько пунктов. У каждого пункта своя разметка. Как реализовать переход на другую активность при нажатии на пункт?

Answer (score 1):

этот код должен помочь

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);}
```

только в место Main2Activity нужно поставить название класса в активность которого необходимо перейти

Answer (score 0):

В адаптере во ViewHolder сделать метод

```
punkt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.punkt)

bind(final MyItem myItem, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
   punkt.setOnClickListener(v->listener.OnItemClick(myItem))
}
```

В самом адаптере нужно сделать:

```
OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
   void onItemClick(Item item)
}
```

И в onBindViewHolder добавить:

```
holder.bind(items.get(position), itemClickListener);
```

В конструктор нужно передавать не только список своих итемов, но и слушатель!

```
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Item> items, OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
   this.items = items;
   this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

При создании переопределите itemClickListener так, чтобы он открывал что нужно - и будет щастье.